# Angular 2 Add values by css selectors and html attributes

Tags: jquery, angular, progress-bar, transclusion

I want to add the following progressbar into my angular 2 project, but I want to use transclusion so that I can pass data from my component that's using it into the value field. This is the progressbar that I want to use:

https://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch

What I'm struggling with is the references to css and html selectors. For instance, the progress bar uses:

```
var $circle = $('#svg #bar');
var r = $circle.attr('r');
var c = Math.PI*(r*2);
$circle.css({ strokeDashoffset: pct});        
$('#cont').attr('data-pct',val);
```

How can I do this type of behavior in angular 2 without using JQUERY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Getting `circle`:

   `var circle = document.getElementById("bar");`
2. Getting `r`:

   `var r = circle.r;
   var c = Math.PI*(r*2);`
3. Setting `strokeDashoffset`:

   `circle.style.strokeDashoffset = pct;`
4. Setting `data-pct`:

   `document.getElementById("cont")["data-pct"] = val;`